# How do you shift char values in an arraylist?

Tags: java, encryption, arraylist, cryptography, shift

I'm trying to code a cipher project where the objective is for a user to send in a text and shift number. The result would be printed accordingly. For instance, if I sent "Hello World" with a shift value of 1, it should print: "Gfmmp Xrsme". The problem is that I'm having trouble with the shifting because I have an arraylist of char values (the alphabet).

This is what I have so far:

```
                import java.util.ArrayList;

                public class CaesarCipher
                {
                int shift;
                String inputText;
                ArrayList<String> arr;
                ArrayList<String> exchange = new ArrayList<String>();

                public CaesarCipher()
                {
                        shift = 0;
                        inputText = "";
                }

                public CaesarCipher(int s, String iT)
                {
                        shift = s;
                        inputText = iT;
                }

                public void alphabet()
                {
                        arr = new ArrayList<String>();
                        arr.add("A");
                        arr.add("B");
                        arr.add("C");
                        arr.add("D");
                        arr.add("E");
                        arr.add("F");
                        arr.add("G");
                        arr.add("H");
                        arr.add("I");
                        arr.add("J");
                        arr.add("K");
                        arr.add("L");
                        arr.add("M");
                        arr.add("N");
                        arr.add("O");
                        arr.add("P");
                        arr.add("Q");
                        arr.add("R");
                        arr.add("S");
                        arr.add("T");
                        arr.add("U");
                        arr.add("V");
                        arr.add("W");
                        arr.add("X");
                        arr.add("Y");
                        arr.add("Z");
                }

                public void convert()
                {
                    String revisedText = inputText.replaceAll("\\s","");
                    //Turn revisedText into an array and match it with array above
                    revisedText.toUpperCase();
                    int j = 1;
                    String letter = "";

                        for (int i = 0; i < revisedText.length(); i++)
                        {
                            exchange.add(revisedText.substring(i, j));
                            j++;
                        }
                }

                public void shift()
                {
                    shift = shift % 26 + 26;
                    ArrayList<String> newArr = new ArrayList<String>(); // array with shifted values
                    int pos = 0;

                    for(int r = 0; r < exchange.size(); r++)
                    {
                     if(arr.get(r).equals(exchange.get(r)))
                        arr.indexOf(r) + shift = pos;
                    }


                }

                public String toString()
                {
                        return "";
                }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is quick for loop for an example

```
    String string = "Hello World";
    String newPhrase = "";
    int shift = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++){
        if(string.charAt(i) != ' ')
            newPhrase += (char)(string.charAt(i) + shift);
        else
            newPhrase += ' ';
    }
    System.out.println(string + " -> " + newPhrase);
```

Output

```
Hello World -> Ifmmp Xpsme
```

However you should note that there are a couple edge cases i am not checking for. Once you understand the above code you should be able to find the edge cases I am talking about.

Comment: What do you mean by edge cases? Sorry, I'm a beginner.

Comment: an edge case would something like, what if we get to a character in the string like a W and our shift is 5. my code will not wrap and grab the B character but instead grab \

Comment: How do you fix that